# Typing: changing type of fieldin inherited class in python

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Let's take:

```
class A:
    pass

class A2(A):
    @property
    def f(self):
        return None

class B:
    def __init__(el: A)
        self._a = el

class B2(B):
    def __init__(el: A2)
        super().__init__(el)

    def m():
        self._a.f()
```

I have now a typing error on the last line when calling `self._a.f()` saying "cannot access member f for type A" even though it's declared at A2 in B, and it has the member.
What is the correct way to declare this snippet for typing to work?

Comment: You forgot `:` after first line `class A`.

Comment: Why would you define `f()` as `@property` in A but in B2 it's a function? this is really confusing

Comment: I'll update the code to remove the confusion. F was just a placeholder name

Comment: Because `self._a` is inferred to be an instance of `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` has no member `f`, so trying to access `_a.f` where `_a: A` is, correctly, an error. To achieve what you want, you should define `f` as an unimplemented function on `A` that its subclasses should implement:

```py
class A:
    @property
    def f(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

or make it an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) with an abstract method:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self): ...
```

This will inform the type checker that `A` and all of its subclasses have a member `f`, and your code should typecheck correctly.

If you want to narrow the type only for `B2._a`, this should be enough:

```py
class B2(B):
    _a: A2

    # rest of class definition
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it the only choice? What if I don't want to extend A's interface since no other class than B2 will need the m method?

Comment: Consider annotating the type of `B2._a` explicitly, by adding `_a: A2` in the class body (not in a method!). That is enough to make the code typecheck on my machine (mypy 0.812). I've edited my answer to include the code.